# Subscribe getting called many times on link click

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this link on html component

```
 <li (click)="select('mydata')" class="m-t-10px">
     <span class="">My Data</span>
 </li>
```

> ts file:

```
select(type: any): void {
 this.Service.ReloadList.next(true);
}

ngOnInit(): void {

 this.Service.ReloadList.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {  
        setTimeout(()=>{                         
          this.loadListData();
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
```

when use click on link comtent will be reloaded `this.loadListData();` this method but in my case on one time click it is called 8-9 times and it is calling api also same 8-9 times on one click.

Comment: Can u add a stackblitz functional example?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of this component? You explicitly subscribe in each instance; whenever the service subject emits, all subscriptions will be fired! Also, it looks like you never unsubscribe. So as components are destroyed and possibly recreated the number of subscriptions with grow.